'pbcopy' or something similar to copy the command to the clipboard literally
echo $(( 1 + 2 )) | pbcopy

This will copy 3 to the clipboard. But how is it possible, the same way, to copy the literal echo $(( 1 + 2 )) string to the clipboard?

print -r -- !! | pbcopy?

@Gairfowl That will copy echo 3 since the arithmetic expansion would be performed before print is run, no? @OP generalizing you want to copy the last command you ran to the clipboard, correct? What about just parsing history? Unless there's a sleeker way that I'm failing to realize

I don't have BSD sed to test this, so beware (this works on Linux, it might need to be adjusted for BSD sed): tac ~/.zsh_history | sed -En '2s/[^;]+;//p' (I think tac also should be swapped for tail -r)? It will print the last command to stdout.

@kos - even worse :) It'll end up as echo ... | pbcopy | pbcopy, so the output of of the first pbcopy(nothing) ends up on the clipboard.

@Gairfowl Yeah it will work (minus the expansion) just the first time around and just for simple cases

print -r -- ${"$(history -n -1)"%%|*} | pbcopy? This is based on @kos's suggestion to use history / fc, has not been tested much.

Using zsh built from git or a future release, and from vi mode, you'll be able to use the vim commands "*yy provided your terminal emulator handles the escape sequence for setting the clipboard.

If you want to copy the current zle buffer to the macos clipboard, you could define a widget such as:
pbcopy-buffer() {
  print -rn -- $BUFFER | pbcopy
}
zle -N pbcopy-buffer

And bind that to a key or key combination of your choice with bindkey as usual.
You could also synchronise the macos paste buffer with zle's own ring buffer by adapting my mouse.zsh (unmaintained, and I've not really used it much myself, it was more a PoC) which does it for X11 selections.

Related: zsh copy and paste like emacs

I tried echo '$(( 1 + 2 ))' in zsh and it echo the literal instead of the calculation so I suppose echo '$(( 1 + 2 ))' | pbcopy should provide the literal too.

But it doesn't include the word echo. Also, I don't want to modify the existing command.
